# What are the downsides of using TPUs instead of GPUs when performing neural network training or inference?

Tags: neural-network, training, gpu, tpu

What are the downsides of using TPUs instead of GPUs when performing neural network training or inference?

From what I read on https://www.predictiveanalyticsworld.com/machinelearningtimes/should-you-choose-a-gpu-or-a-tpu-to-train-your-machine-learning-models/10460/ there are only upsides:

[image]